# Looped div with "select" tag changes every select's value when using only one of them in Angular

Tags: html, angular, forms, drop-down-menu, ngfor

I have some trouble understanding how property binding and NgModel works in Angular especially with forms.
I have one case where I want to be able to have several inputs with the same options (in the same form), meaning that I loop a div with the aid of a counter, and each select that is created has its options looped through an array of names.

The problem is that each time I change one of the select's value, every other select changes aswell, which is not the behavior I was expected. I want each select to have its own value and be able to send each one independently of the other.

Here is the portion of code of the form I'm working on :

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="linkToSeveralObj">
 <label for="type">Objet/s à lier</label><br/>
 <span *ngFor="let in of counter(nbObj); let i = index">
   <div *ngIf="i == nbObj-1;else oblock"><select class="custom-select" name="severalObjToLink{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="form.severalObjToLink" required>
     <option *ngFor="let o of allObj" [value]="o.internName">{{o.internName}}</option>
   </select><a (click)="addSelect()" class="ml-3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></div>
  <ng-template #oblock>
    <select class="custom-select" name="severalObjToLink{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="form.severalObjToLink" required>
      <option *ngFor="let o of allObj" [value]="o.internName">{{o.internName}}</option>
    </select><br/><br/></ng-template></span>
    <div *ngIf="f.submitted && severalObjToLink.invalid">
      <div *ngIf="severalObjToLink.errors.required">Les objets à lier sont requis</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The code may seem a little be complicated for what I'm trying to achieve for pure aesthetic reasons. Basically I wanted to have a plus clickable icon next to each new select added by the user in the form, but only next to the last one added, so I used ng-templates with conditions.

I'm guessing there is a problem with the names. If someone could help me with the issue I'd be glad, thanks in advance

EDIT 2 : Problem solved, see the updated code below :

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="linkToSeveralObj">
 <label for="type">Objet/s à lier</label><br/>
 <span *ngFor="let in of counter(nbObj); let i = index">
   <div *ngIf="i == nbObj-1;else oblock"><select class="custom-select" name="severalObjToLink{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="severalObjToLink[i]" required>
     <option *ngFor="let o of allObj" [value]="o.internName">{{o.internName}}</option>
   </select><a (click)="addSelect()" class="ml-3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></div>
  <ng-template #oblock>
    <select class="custom-select" name="severalObjToLink{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="severalObjToLink[i]" required>
      <option *ngFor="let o of allObj" [value]="o.internName">{{o.internName}}</option>
    </select><br/><br/></ng-template></span>
    <div *ngIf="f.submitted && severalObjToLink[i].invalid">
      <div *ngIf="severalObjToLink[i].errors.required">Les objets à lier sont requis</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What's in `form.severalObjToLink`, "I'm gessing there is a problem with the names" why not assign dynamic names based on the index?

Comment: Indeed, I have been trying to use "form.severalObjToLink[i]" aswell without realising the stupidity of the thing, just had to declare an array in my component. It's working now